# How to change TCP Header and options using Python's socket library

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, packet, mtu

I will like to get some help on how to modify the TCP header as well as change the options on a TCP header. I am especially interested in the MSS section of the options.

I have tried using the setsockopt() with different options to no success.

Here is some code attempting to change the MSS:

```py
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    #! Settings mss
    s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.IP_OPTIONS , b"MSS:400")
```

I expect the MSS to change to 400. The code runs but it doesn't change the MSS (inspected with Wireshark).

Comment: `b"MSS:400"` is not the correct value of the MSS option in the TCP header. TCP header options aren't strings, they're numbers. MSS is option number 2, length = 4, value = 2 bytes containing the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `TCP_MAXSEG` option.

```
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_MAXSEG, 400)
```

Comment: Awesome works on Linux! This will not work on Windows I am guessing due to lack of raw socket support?!

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with raw sockets.

Comment: ```sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_MAXSEG, 400)
print(sock.getsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_MAXSEG))```
MSS -> 536
Not working

Answer (score 0):

in addition to what @Barmar said, you can find more info in the "man pages" on any unix system by typing one of:

```sh
man 7 ip
man 7 tcp
man 7 udp
```

`man` is short for manual, `7` is [overview/misc section](https://linux.die.net/man/7/intro)

the [tcp page](https://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp) says this about `TCP_MAXSEG`:

> The maximum segment size for outgoing TCP packets.  In Linux 2.2 and earlier, and in
>                 Linux 2.6.28 and later, if this option is set before  connection  establishment,  it
>                 also changes the MSS value announced to the other end in the initial packet.  Values
>                 greater than the (eventual) interface MTU have no effect.  TCP will also impose  its
>                 minimum and maximum bounds over the value provided.

Comment: Awesome, Good Tip!